# Forza Motorsport 3 co-op career

Tags: forza-motorsport-3

In Forza Motorsport 3 for the XBox 360, the only place where I can see a "Splitscreen" option is in the single race mode.

Can I start an offline, splitscreen co-op career mode?

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't. There is no co-op mode in Forza 3.

Comment: the closest to coop me and my mate got was passing the controller. might be an idea for f4.

Answer (score 0):

The Splitscreen title is just a game for **local multiplayer** (2 controllers), not for co-op or online.